# Quartz2D how to save the current context and then draw over it?

Tags: iphone, quartz-2d

I'm trying to draw using Quartz2D and but i'm finding the drawing to lag a lot right after a few dots. Therefore I am wondering how can I cache the current context into a bmp or a jpg or a layer and then draw onto the layer again to make the drawing smoother. Which way is the best way to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, Quartz2D uses a painting model to render content, and once you draw something you can't interact with it at all, so I don't see why caching the current context would do anything to help.

However, if you want to cache your current context, the code looks something like this:

```
// Begin image context
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);

[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
CGImageRef screenshotRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
UIImage *screenshot = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:screenshotRef];

// End image context
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
// Release CGImage
CGImageRelease(screenshotRef);

return screenshot;
```

Comment: Yes, what I want is to do it using a painting model. However my current implementation saves all previous touched points into an array and redraw them every frame. Hence it stacks up quickly and lags the program dramatically. Is this code used inside the viewcontroller? I want something that I can use and save inside drawRect function. I dunno if I'm not thinking it correctly? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You do not want to save the current drawing inside a drawRect function.  The graphics pipeline flush can be very slow.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of drawing in a UIView's drawRect and trying to save that drawing layer, you might want to try drawing into a bitmap in a background thread.  You never have to clear the bitmap and can just keep drawing into it.  Then all you have to do in the UIView drawRect is one image draw of the latest bitmap available, which iOS can do fairly quickly.

Answer (score 0):

*You can draw one layer to another layer by first converting different layers to images and  converge into single Unit.*

```
    //Draw path and return Image
    let firstBeizerPath:UIImage = drawPath(firstBeizerpath: drawCircle())
    let secondBeizerPath:UIImage = drawPath(firstBeizerpath: polygon())

    //Draw different saved context into single image.
    let image = UIImage(). drawOneLayerOverAnother(firstImage:firstBeizerPath , secondImage:secondBeizerPath)

extension UIImage {
    func drawOneLayerOverAnother(firstImage:UIImage , secondImage:UIImage ) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(firstLayer.size)

    firstImage.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: firstLayer.size.width, height: firstLayer.size.height) )
    secondImage.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: firstLayer.size.width, height: firstLayer.size.height) )

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage!
    }
}
```

[Demo App](https://github.com/shrawan2015/Application-Demo-StackOverFlow/tree/master/CGContextDrawImageDemo)